# Overriding __new__ to pre-process arguments and create a subclass

Tags: python, class, constructor, subclass

I've got a base class, `_BaseWidget`, which is not instantiated. It's got many `abstractmethod`s to be filled in by sub-classes like `AppleWidget` and `PearWidget` which are actually instantiated and used.

However, **for convenience**, I'd like to make the `_BaseWiget` constructor usable, and produce an appropriate sub-class if called.

I *want to* write something like this:

```py
class _BaseWidget:
    def __init__(self, parameter1, parameter2=None):
        if isinstance(parameter1, AppleSeed):
            return AppleWidget(_prepare_apple(parameter1, color=parameter2))
        elif isinstance(parameter1, PearSeed)
            return PearWidget(_prepare_pear(parameter1))
        raise ValueError("convenience constructor couldn't guess what you're trying to do. please just instantiate the appropriate subclass directly")
```

However, I'm running up against two issues:

1. `__init__` can't override which class is created.
2. `__new__` can't access parameters passed to the constructor, which I *would* like to pre-process slightly in this stage before passing them to the subclass constructors.

Is it possible to do both of these at the same time? Again, I want to provide a slightly simplified "convenience" interface to the base class constructor that will do pre-processing on the arguments before giving them to the actual subclasses.

Comment: *"`__new__` can't access parameters passed to the constructor"* - this is incorrect.  See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__): "The remaining arguments [to `__new__`] are those passed to the object constructor expression (the call to the class)."

Comment: Rather than overload `__new__`, though, you should define a separate class method.

Comment: But, the base class isn't really the place to define something that depends on any specific subclasses. Just define a regular factory method.

Comment: Why wouldn't `_prepare_apple` be called inside `AppleWidget.__init__`?